# Adding values into an array in python and returning index when target is breached

Tags: python

I am new to python.
I am trying to create a simple function that creates an array.

- First value 10 second 10+40 third 10+40+40 fourth 10+40+40+40 and so
- Once it reaches the specific value(374 or the next nearest number ), it returns that the index of this value.

.

```
f = []
x = 10
g = 40
y = 374
f.append(x)
for i in range(1,20):
    f.append(g+x)
    g += g + x

final = y
for number in f:
    if final <= number:
       final = number
```

---

Is there another way than using range ? my current get the max number in array and that is not my intention,i want to get the index of the first value that equals 374 if not doesn't exits the next the index of the nearst value

Comment: Ok, and what's the problem? Is there an error message? Is the output incorrect? Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way you can structure your logic:

```
import itertools

def get_index(start=10, increment=40, target=374):
    """Return index starting from 0 when value breaches target"""
    for index in itertools.count():
        start += increment
        if start > target:
            return index

get_index()  # 9
```

It's worth noting that this is a long-winded way of calculating `int((374-10)/40) = 9`

**Explanation**

- Use `itertools.count()` to count to an arbitrary limit. You *could* use `range(x)` instead if you wish to specify an upper bound.
- Increment the `start` value using `+=` operator. This is equivalent to `start = start + increment`.
- `return` the relevant index when the target is breached.
- Note that building a list or array is unnecessary and potentially expensive for this particular task.

Comment: Yes those are exactly the values that are calculated. But your question states that you wan to *return the index*, which is exactly what this function does. What *exactly* do you want as the output?

Comment: Now i got your solution, thanks,it is exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
variable += something
```

is equivalent to:

```
variable = variable + something
```

So when you write:

```
g += g + x
```

it's equivalent to:

```
g = g + g + x
```

so you add `g` twice. You want either

```
g = g + x
```

or

```
g += x
```

Comment: Thank for you answer. The values should be 10,50,90,130,170,210 and so on

Comment: then I think you should be doing `x += g` and appending `x` to the array.

Comment: Thanks your answer and comment helped me to clarify the +=